# How to fill up char with string after allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, character

I have this structure:

```
struct student {
  int id;
  string name;
  string surname;
};
```

What I need to do is to make function with this declaration:

```
char* surname_name (student Student)
```

which will format every Student that I put in format like this "surname, name" and it will bring back pointer on it.

What I've done so far is this:

```
char* surname_name (student Student){
    char *pointer= (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*(Student.name.length + Student.surname.length + 2)); // + 2 because of space and comma

    string::iterator it;
    int i=0;

    for (it= Student.surname.begin(); it != Student.surname.end(); it++){
        (*pointer)[i] = it; // here it gives me error
    }

    ... // here still should be added code for comma, space and name
    return pointer;
}
```

I can't make it anyhow else, because it's in the task that function needs to have this declaration. How to make this properly?

Comment: Do you really need it as a `char*`? Would a `std::string` not be much better? If you need it like that, I recommend taking a `char*` as an argument for the user to pass their own allocated buffer to.

Comment: Yea, I would definitely use it immediately string, but I can't. Need to use this because later I need to make other function which will take this function as argument, so I can't modify declaration.

Comment: Could you not return a `std::string` and then use the `c_str` member function to get it as a `char*`?

Comment: You can do the concatenation in a string and then you can just malloc some memory, memcopy the string into it, and return that. It would be much easier that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
char * surname_name (student Student){
    return strdup((Student.surname + ", " + Student.name).c_str());
}
```

Comment: I get this error: error C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details.

Comment: Using _strdup instead of strdup on Windows platforms

Comment: it works now :). @Joel, when should I free the pointer when I'm getting it back with return?

Comment: If you don't free it at some point, you will have a memory leak.  strdup allocates the pointer with malloc.

Answer (score 1):

```
(*pointer)[i] = it;
```

should be

```
*(pointer+i) = *it; //assigning the current char to correct position
```

you should also increase `i` properly.

You can also do it with `std::string` which can do simple concatenation.

Comment: I made this, and "i" is underlined as mistake and it's written : "Error: expression must have pointer-to-object type"

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
string surname_name (const student &Student)
{
    return Student.name + " " + Student.surname;
}

// ...

do_something( surname_name(student).c_str() );
```

If you really want to return a pointer, you can do it as below:

```
char *surname_name (const student &Student)
{
    string s = Student.name + " " + Student.surname;
    char *p = new char [s.length()+1];
    strcpy(p, s.c_str());
    return p;
}
```

Don't forget to `delete` the returned pointer.

Comment: It's worth the cost of an extra copy to have the code be readable.

Comment: Also, it doesn't have extra copy, because of the RVO.

Comment: Sadly, it does.  You've copied it once creating the new string, then explicitly done a strcpy.  Most string implementations are not copy on write.  RVO only applies to the last statement, when creating a temporary.  In this case, you're returning a pointer, so it doesn't apply.  It would be possible just to copy directly into the character array rather than creating the string, but that's more error prone and harder to maintain.

Comment: Aha, You're talking about pointer based solution. Yes, it has extra copy. Agree.